# How to merge 2D scene and 3D scene together in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am currently building a game in 3D but i want to add a level in 2D,
how to add a 2D scene to a 3D project.

If this is possible using c# script not with Orthographic projection on the camera.

Comment: Unity technically is only 3d.   2d is just how you look at it

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Also just because you use a certain IDE at some point in your development doesn't mean you are asking specifically about that IDE (`visual-studio`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity, 2D and 3D are just a conversion of perspective. All objects have 3D coordinate information. When Vector3 is converted to Vector2 and the view mode is changed from perspective to orthogonal, the Z-axis information is meaningless. So, it changed from 3D to 2D. Select "Editor" under "Project Settings" in "Editor", change the "Mode" of "Default Behaviour Mode" under "Editor Settings" to "3D", and then "Ctrl + N" to create a new scene , this time is 3D development mode

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps you have to do to make a 2D looking scene:

1. Create a camera object
2. Set the view to 'Ortographic'
3. Set its transform to look at the Z axis forward/backward
4. Use Sprite renderers :)